# My variables automatically updates... when I only set it once. Why does this happen?

Tags: dart

In my home_page of my app I have some logic that grabs the some data from a class (CircleData) and sets a variable equal to it. (simplified example for so it's easier to explain).

My class:

```
class CircleData {
static List circle1 = [1];
}
```

In my homepage I have a button that when pressed makes variable x equal to the List from CircleData, like this:

```
x = CircleData.circle1;
```

I then go on to modify the circle1 List in the class (from a different button in a different page). I end up switching its value to [1, 2, 3] so now it looks as follows:

```
class CircleData {
static List circle1 = [1, 2, 3];
}
```

I then go back to my home_page and try to print x and instead of printing '[1]' as expected it prints '[1, 2, 3]'. Why does this happen? Why does my x value that I only set ONCE to the value of circle1 suddenly change and update alongside circle1? Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

ANOTHER VERSION:

So I am making a game where there is a pile of circles on the screen. The list in the class:

```
class CircleData {
static List circle1 = [1];
}
```

is where all my scripts are depositing the changed versions of the stack of circles (you modify the stack as the game goes on). So the list here changes to maybe [1, 4, 18, 3] and then to [1, 45, 4] as an example after every turn. After every turn I want there to be an option to undo your last turn. I am trying to implement this in the following fashion: Right before the list is modified at the end of the turn I create a new list (copy of circle1 from the class) right before everything changes and the turn ends. Then when the player presses the undo button the copied version of circle1 (i originally called it x) becomes the new value of circle1, hence undoing the last turn. The only problem is that my variable (x, the copied version of circle1 right before the turn ends and real circle1 is updated) updates to my circle1 when the turn changes. I want it to be independent so I can set circle1 to it if they player chooses to undo.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Thanks! How would you recommend I fix this?

Comment: My previous comment was likely not accurate. Could you simplify your code less?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore ok I added a deeper explanation. Hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 1):

After @ChristopherMoore told me it was a reference or something I did some research and figured out a way to assign without making it a reference. Assigning it without making it a reference solved my problem.

This type of assignment didn't work: (where a and b are lists)

```
List a = b;
```

This type worked: (where a and b are lists)

```
List a = List.from(b);
```

Comment: Assignment always creates a reference.  What `List a = List.from(b)` does is creates a *copy* and then makes `a` refer to the copy.  Also, you usually should prefer `List.of` over `List.from`, which does static type-checking instead of runtime type-checking. (In your case it doesn't matter since your lists use a `dynamic` element type.)